# Quasibinomial GLMM with LASSO regularization in R

Tags: r, lasso, glmm, quasi-likelihood

I am currently assessing drivers of deforestation using a GLM (generalised linear model) with LASSO regularization (using package glmnet in R). As the response variable is % of area deforested I have been using a quasi-binomial distribution (with model performance checks to make sure residuals etc are kosher). I have not used binomial distribution so that I don't need to set arbitrary %deforested thresholds between forest and not forest.

However, I want to assess if the relationship between one of the covariates and the response term differs between regions (i.e. a random slope in a mixed effects model).

Are there any R packages that can run GLMM with LASSO regularization that allow quasi-binomial distribution? Or are there any other ways to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Would you please clarify what you mean by "random effects between the response and one of the model terms"?

Comment: So is region a random factor? If not, it sounds like you simply need to include the region:covariate interaction (a fixed effect) in your model.

Comment: Yes, region is the random factor. I think it should also be possible to use a region:covariate interaction but I am not familiar with how to do this with a LASSO regression in R either. I have been using the glmnet package to-date and have tried to create an interaction term using model.matrix with no success.